# Is it possible to align a button within a Rebol / Red panel?

Tags: rebol, red

Would like to do something like this except button is not really in the middle

```
  v: [text "test" field "test"
      return
      button middle
  ]
  view v
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Red/VID dialect is capable of [aligning faces](https://doc.red-lang.org/en/vid.html#_layout) in the current row/column, but not yet centering it relatively to its parent face. The current way to achieve it is to explicitly call the `center-face` function, once the face tree has been constructed:

```
v: layout [
    size 500x200
    text "test" field "test" return 
    b: button "ok" 
]
center-face/x b
view v
```

Answer (score 0):

A way for people who still want to know:

```
boyut: system/view/screens/1/size
orta: boyut * 1x0 / 2.6
view [
  size boyut
  origin orta
  ; faces
]
```